# what happen Onclick In Fileupload Browser buttons

Tags: javascript, html

i have a small doubt i.e when i click on FileUpload Browser Button how  will the browser opens files contains window

what method called when we click FileUpload Browser Button

Comment: I don't understand. It will be some internal function differing from browser to browser, why do you want to know its name? It should not be accessible from within Javascript.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635377/how-to-make-own-file-upload-using-html-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The basic html would be:

```
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
```

Is that what you were asking for?

I think this question might help you out:

[How to make own file upload using HTML and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635377/how-to-make-own-file-upload-using-html-and-javascript)

Comment: I think I did not understand teh question? :S

Comment: ya i know but wa happen when i click on Browser button

Comment: my requirement is their is a on box when i click on that the browser open files window hoe to write it

Comment: @Narendra Do you mean the "box" where you browse the files? that is native to the os (in this case)

Comment: @Narendra please be more clear about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the default behavior of the browser or "write" something to that window.

Most you can do is change the appearance of the file input button, but after it's clicked the window letting the user choose a file can't be changed.